# Borderlands 2 silently quits after pressing "play" in launcher

Tags: borderlands-2

I have two installations of Borderlands on different PCs. On first one everything gone without problems at all, but on the second one game just silently closes without any messages when I click play in launcher. Trying to go into game directly with `-NoLauncher` doesn't help either.

I tried reinstalling .NET, reinstalling MSVC runtime, reinstalling video drivers,providing file with Steam app ID, completely reinstalling game, copying complete installation from one PC to another - nothing helped. Process briefly appears in taskbar and task manager and then disappears again in a few seconds. Also it seems that there's no error logs in pretty much anywhere I could think of checking, including same location where I see startup logs for successful installation on first PC.

Pretty much every other game runs fine and this is not video card problem either, as exactly same VGA that is now installed in second PC was in first one just a few weeks ago and I did run Borderlands 2 on it successfully.

The only difference I can name is amount of available memory and that second PC have 32-bit system.

How can I successfully run game or at least track what exactly is causing problem?

Comment: Check your event log to see what is causing the crash. Type eventvwr.msc in your run option or just the search area. Look in the application section after the game crashes for more detailed info.

Comment: @Sorean, zero new entries on launch/quiting.

Comment: Did you purchase through Steam or standalone?

Comment: @Sorean, Steam, and quick online searches shows multiple forum topics about same thing spanning several dozens of pages. Reinstalling/revalidating doesn't help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally it seems that problem was in Steam installation itself - some libraries got lost and Borderlands react to it worse than other games. Refreshing Steam installation made game run just fine.